# Images with @1x @2x suffix do not appear in app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I am struggling with an issue in an app with a couple of custom images in the navigation bar. This was all working perfectly well until yesterday, when the images stopped appearing in the navigation bar.

There is a clue that, when I add one of the images to a view controller via the xib editor, I get a warning message e.g. `Could not load the "back-arrow.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.test.myapp"`

What does work is renaming the files from e.g. `back-arrow@2x.png` to `back-arrow.png` - but then its displayed at the wrong size. I managed to get one of the images working and displaying correctly yesterday, but in trying to get another image to display it has disappeared again.

I have checked the files are present in Copy Bundle Resources. They appear in the Xcode image browser.

**EDIT:** 
When I delete the @1x images, the icons appear again. What might be going on here?

Using Xcode 8.1, testing both in simulator (iOS 10) and iPad 2 (iOS 9).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198946/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-with-identifier

Comment: Please note that reference to images in the xib/storyboard are _sans_ extension (so `myImage` instead of `myImage.png`)

Comment: are you using .xcassets folder ?

Comment: @EmelElias yes I am using `.xcassets` folder

Comment: @EmelElias actually, I was not using `.xcassets` folder! Thanks for the clue.

Comment: @Adamski so is the issue resolved, if so an up vote will be encouraging  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The images were not in the `.xcassets` folder, just added as Resources. I did it the proper way and made each image into an Imageset, and it now works as intended.