# Swift - Images not displaying

Tags: swift, image, uinavigationcontroller

Loaded a couple of icons for a tab controller and they are not displaying at all.

Error message is:
Could not load the "xxxx.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier...

The images are there. The image will be displayed if I use an old image that has been in the build since the start???

Read around this error and CocoaPods and all Pods are up to date...

Any ideas?

Comment: share image of your xib or storybord image of tabbar , are you write in code or from storybord

Comment: So the images are inside your assets folder and you don't have a typo in your image names? Are the images displayed in your storyboard?

Comment: take a look to this answer maybe it will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198946/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-with-identifier?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: They display perfectly in the Storyboard....

Comment: I had looked through that link. I have cleaned the system, and rebooted.I have removed the images and added them in. If I try and add them the way I used to I get the "An assistant session is already running on this window". So added them into the folder and then added them. They have a "?" against them rather than an "A". Is that part of the issue?

Comment: I had the same issue. but none of the solutions work for me. if any one fixed the problem please share the solution with me.

Answer (score 1):

- Select #yourProject on Project navigator (blue icon)
- Select #yourProject on Targets tab (real app icon)
- Select Build Phases
- Open Copy Bundle Resources
- Hit + and add all the images

The reference basically disappeared for running.

Ctrl + Cmd + K and run ;)

Answer (score 0):

The previous technique of "Files/Add files to..." appears not to work. What does work is to have Xcode opened, but not maximised, then open Finder and drag the required image files over. Compile and they will then appear. Simples, once you know how but that's programming.