# swift cannot loading images after update

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview

Have just installed XCode update and got a very strange problem with the simplest image loading. I made a basic image-view and combined it with simple png. Got the following message:

> 2017-09-20 15:56:22.596882+0200 TestingImageView[1253:126865] Could
>   not load the "banana.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle
>   with identifier "swift-simplest.TestingImageView

Have you any idea what could the reason be?

The code is almost non-existent:

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var testIV: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Update: Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388183/xcode-9-could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-with-identi)

Comment: Have you tried the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571709/5576310) answer?

Comment: Yes, I seen it and try to fulfill clean and loaded images once more. The same result.