# xcode 9 Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Tags: xcode, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I moved to Xcode 9.0 yesterday, but image resources don't work. I dragged image to root and select "Copy if needed" and "Create groups" and add to my project targets.

The image is shown in storyboard but it is not shown in Simulator or even device.

I get this warning "2017-09-24 11:49:46.578312+0330 testResource[3999:148745] Could not load the "past_exam_background.jpg" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.app.testResource".I tested png and the result was the same.

what should I do?

[image: xcode 9 Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click on a picture file in Xcode. in attribute on bottom you'll see Target membership. Check the box and it is gonna work. Had the same problem see picture:
[image]

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Comment: could not find this silly error . thanks . it works now .