# Runtime warning: Could not load the image "imageName" referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "bundleId"

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, xib, nsbundle

This is **not** duplicate of [Could not load the “” image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31198946/1971013) because all answers assume image and XIB bundle are the same. Answers deal with all kinds of other issues; there is no explanation how to have XIB and images in separate targets.

I have a XIB which is member of Xcode target `TargetA`, a framework.

The XIB has a few images that are in `TargetB`, the main app. They are in an asset catalog.

At the moment I get a runtime warning: `Could not load the image "imageName" referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "bundleIdA"`.

How can I make sure that such images are loaded?

Comment: @meaning-matters can you validate both targets are selected for asset catalog (i.e `*.xcassets`) if yes removing and adding image name `imageName` should fix the issue.

Comment: @Satish But I don't want both targets selected.

Comment: It's not a duplicate I think.  Can someone please point out which of the 17 answers in the supposed duplicate covers my issue?