# I have a problem when I set button image using the code "setImage"

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I have a problem when I set the button image using this code:

```
button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flight_deselect")**.changeToLightGrayLightTint(), for: .normal)
```

It's working good on iPhone but it is crashing on iPad.

Please refer to this code:

```
func changeButtonState(_ type: ModuleDetails, _ isSelected: Bool, _ button: UIButton) {
    switch type {
    case .Flight:
        if isSelected {
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flight_select").changeToPrimaryLightTint(), for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flight_deselect").changeToLightGrayLightTint(), for: .normal)
        }
    case .Hotel:
        if isSelected {
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotel_select").changeToPrimaryLightTint(), for: .normal)
        } else {
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "hotel_deselect").changeToLightGrayLightTint(), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

crash log

> Could not load the "flight_select" image referenced from a nib in the
>   bundle with identifier

Comment: What is crash report showing?

Comment: @NikunjRajyaguru Log => Could not load the "flight_select" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198946/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-with-identifier

Comment: @NikunjRajyaguru I referred the link, My project Target membership also already enabled.

Comment: how and where do you call this function it is important to solve that problem and understand is it an iphone ipad difference

Comment: This function is called in the Navigation lunching screen, which means App menu screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check The "Devices" field of your image

[image]

Comment: It's Working! Thank you!