# iOS Scene can't load any images

Tags: ios, json, swift, uikit, uiimage

This is similar (but not a duplicate, please read) of:
[Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198946/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-with-identifier?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

I have a scene that loads other elements (e.g. textfields, labels, etc...) but each of the images throws the "Could not load ... image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier" warning from the above question.

After trying all of the answers, I noticed that one of the images loads fine in a different scene. I tried cycling across known good images and the error persists.

So while that previous question assumes the warning is correct to indicate a problem with the image and how it's referenced; my problem seems to be different. Something about the scene makes it unable to reference any of its images.

I'm using a single storyboard, and the other scenes don't have this problem. The only thing different is that I'm trying to use a "present modally" segue, although I launch from code the same as my other view controllers:

```
        guard let alert = createPopUp(titled: Labels.Alerts.netError,
                                      message: Labels.Alerts.aErrorMsg,
                                      actions: [emptyDone]) else { return }
        
        present(alert, animated: animated)
```

and I modify the vc here...

```
/// This method creates a custom view controller as an alternative to default alert view.
///
/// - Parameter title:          The title text for alert view.
/// - Parameter message:        The message text for alert view.
/// - Parameter needsTextField: If true a text input field is shown.
/// - Parameter actions:        The actions to use when buttons are tapped.
func createPopUp(titled title: String, message: String, needsTextField: Bool = false, actions: [CustomAlertAction]? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: ElId.VCs.main, bundle: Bundle.module)
    guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ElId.VCs.alert)
            as? AlertViewController else { return nil }

    vc.titleText = title
    vc.messageText = message
    vc.showField = needsTextField
    
    if let actions = actions {
        if actions.count < 2 {
            let action = actions.first
            vc.centerAction = action ?? CustomAlertAction(type: .cancel, action: nil)
        } else {
            vc.leftAction = actions[0]
            vc.rightAction = actions[1]
        }
    } else {
        vc.centerAction = CustomAlertAction(type: .cancel, action: nil)
    }
    
    return vc
}
```

**What is causing the scene to not be able to load any images?**

My ViewController is found, the image shows up in the Attribute Inspector, the entire assets file is targeted and I'm including a screenshot of the image view from the storyboard below. I've wiped the project, rebooted, renamed/reloaded images and cycled to others. Using Xcode 13.3.1. Here's the source for the scene:

```
    <!--Alert View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="Szf-uc-DRk">
        <objects>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="CustomAlertView" id="hJd-Qa-reL" customClass="AlertViewController" customModule="Trenches_Engine" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" opaque="NO" alpha="0.75" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="RTJ-We-B4x">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="896" height="414"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" image="greyCorners" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="voc-d2-qDg">
                            <rect key="frame" x="323" y="86.5" width="250" height="220"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="250" id="Df6-eK-Vdg"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="220" id="up1-yu-Uas"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </imageView>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" showsTouchWhenHighlighted="YES" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gbF-Zi-LTA">
                            <rect key="frame" x="428" y="251.5" width="40" height="40"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.57536304000000005" green="0.57924687860000001" blue="0.31759420040000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="40" id="sAP-Uv-ilr"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="tjw-Bo-xiO"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <state key="normal" backgroundImage="button_next">
                                <color key="titleColor" systemColor="systemRedColor"/>
                            </state>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="centerActionTapped:" destination="hJd-Qa-reL" eventType="touchUpInside" id="EAm-Yf-LyM"/>
                                <action selector="exitButtonTapped:" destination="agu-LA-vjs" eventType="touchUpInside" id="POV-Wd-7AJ"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" showsTouchWhenHighlighted="YES" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="clq-WK-lNk">
                            <rect key="frame" x="456" y="251.5" width="40" height="40"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.57536304000000005" green="0.57924687860000001" blue="0.31759420040000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            <state key="normal" backgroundImage="button_next">
                                <color key="titleColor" systemColor="systemRedColor"/>
                            </state>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="exitButtonTapped:" destination="agu-LA-vjs" eventType="touchUpInside" id="fTW-49-BdN"/>
                                <action selector="rightActionTapped:" destination="hJd-Qa-reL" eventType="touchUpInside" id="IMe-xj-I5F"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" showsTouchWhenHighlighted="YES" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aFM-Xc-Ojp">
                            <rect key="frame" x="400" y="251.5" width="40" height="40"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.57536304000000005" green="0.57924687860000001" blue="0.31759420040000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="Jy4-iG-Nuf"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="40" id="hym-qb-Q6f"/>
                            </constraints>
                            <state key="normal" backgroundImage="button_back">
                                <color key="titleColor" systemColor="systemRedColor"/>
                            </state>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="exitButtonTapped:" destination="agu-LA-vjs" eventType="touchUpInside" id="w7y-iy-Hac"/>
                                <action selector="leftActionTapped:" destination="hJd-Qa-reL" eventType="touchUpInside" id="5o5-d6-Xwf"/>
                            </connections>
                        </button>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Title" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OAb-vD-zI5">
                            <rect key="frame" x="419" y="96.5" width="58" height="37"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" style="UICTFontTextStyleTitle0"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.57536304000000005" green="0.57924687860000001" blue="0.31759420040000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="70Z-Dh-8e4">
                            <rect key="frame" x="427" y="141.5" width="42" height="21"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" style="UICTFontTextStyleTitle3"/>
                            <color key="textColor" white="0.33333333329999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                        </label>
                        <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PMo-i7-t7T">
                            <rect key="frame" x="338" y="215.5" width="220" height="31"/>
                            <color key="tintColor" red="0.57536304000000005" green="0.57924687860000001" blue="0.31759420040000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            <color key="textColor" red="0.57536304000000005" green="0.57924687860000001" blue="0.31759420040000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                    </subviews>
                    <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="s7n-oq-I15"/>
                    <color key="tintColor" white="0.33333333329999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    <accessibility key="accessibilityConfiguration">
                        <accessibilityTraits key="traits" notEnabled="YES"/>
                    </accessibility>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="PMo-i7-t7T" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-60" id="40f-iI-SMg"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="gbF-Zi-LTA" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="aFM-Xc-Ojp" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="5lR-Op-TJN"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="voc-d2-qDg" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="s7n-oq-I15" secondAttribute="centerX" id="6Ug-r9-GEH"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="clq-WK-lNk" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="aFM-Xc-Ojp" secondAttribute="width" id="6yg-vP-Vts"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="OAb-vD-zI5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="top" constant="10" id="9RB-RC-uGT"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="PMo-i7-t7T" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="leading" constant="15" id="DMN-S8-PTV"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="70Z-Dh-8e4" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="OAb-vD-zI5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="Kmv-xJ-co9"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="voc-d2-qDg" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="s7n-oq-I15" secondAttribute="centerY" id="L9G-3A-4Qc"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="aFM-Xc-Ojp" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="gbF-Zi-LTA" secondAttribute="centerY" id="QuK-hN-Yi0"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="clq-WK-lNk" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="aFM-Xc-Ojp" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="SEM-O3-w2D"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="OAb-vD-zI5" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="centerX" id="T6d-t4-Chx"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="gbF-Zi-LTA" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Wnn-jI-hYZ"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="gbF-Zi-LTA" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="PMo-i7-t7T" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1.28333" id="X8c-jf-MQL"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="PMo-i7-t7T" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-15" id="YI5-pL-pem"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="clq-WK-lNk" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="aFM-Xc-Ojp" secondAttribute="height" id="YJu-FK-omI"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="gbF-Zi-LTA" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-15" id="ZJA-OZ-aqL"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="gbF-Zi-LTA" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="clq-WK-lNk" secondAttribute="centerY" id="pGb-qE-pjW"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="70Z-Dh-8e4" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="voc-d2-qDg" secondAttribute="centerX" id="sVz-sW-X4m"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="centerActionButton" destination="gbF-Zi-LTA" id="pzg-Yg-7mR"/>
                    <outlet property="leftActionButton" destination="aFM-Xc-Ojp" id="31k-No-rUt"/>
                    <outlet property="messageLabel" destination="70Z-Dh-8e4" id="Av9-q7-mpK"/>
                    <outlet property="rightActionButton" destination="clq-WK-lNk" id="MRb-84-gQx"/>
                    <outlet property="textField" destination="PMo-i7-t7T" id="AQB-lV-Dzf"/>
                    <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="OAb-vD-zI5" id="3gn-dY-Srl"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="p3b-vT-mKf" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="717" y="1649"/>
    </scene>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Tried removing the segue and it still happens.

Created a new project with a single scene, gave it a button to trigger the create pop up, pasted my scene and the code shown here into the project and it all works as expected. Tried repasting the scene into my original project, but still fails. Deleted derived data and tried re-adding all files again...still having the issue!!!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's VC...

```
import UIKit

final class AlertViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var leftAction: CustomAlertAction?

    var centerAction: CustomAlertAction?

    var rightAction: CustomAlertAction?

    var titleText: String?

    var messageText: String?

    var showField: Bool = false

    // MARK: - Properties: IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var leftActionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerActionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightActionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Functions
    
    // MARK: - Functions: IBActions

    @IBAction func leftActionTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.leftAction?.action?()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func centerActionTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.centerAction?.action?()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func rightActionTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.rightAction?.action?()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Functions: UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        decorateViewController()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if showField {
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func decorateViewController() {        
//        setBGImage(titled: Assets.IMG.alertBg)
        setValues()
    }
    
    private func setValues() {
        titleLabel.text = titleText
        messageLabel.text = messageText
        
        configureLabel(titleLabel, sized: FontSize.small)
        configureLabel(messageLabel, with: Colors.grey, sized: FontSize.extraSmall, numLines: 2)
        configureButtons()
        configureTextField()
    }
    
    private func configureTextField() {
        textField.isHidden = !showField
        textField.keyboardType = .alphabet
        textField.delegate = self
    }
    
    private func configureButtons() {
        leftActionButton.isHidden = leftAction == nil
        centerActionButton.isHidden = centerAction == nil
        rightActionButton.isHidden = rightAction == nil
        
        leftActionButton.isEnabled = leftAction?.isEnabled ?? false
        centerActionButton.isEnabled = centerAction?.isEnabled ?? false
        rightActionButton.isEnabled = rightAction?.isEnabled ?? false
        
        // TODO: Set button image alpha based on style...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue involved using Swift Package manager.

I moved most of my storyboard over to a Swift Package, but kept the original main.storyboard in the app because I haven't figured out a way to fully get rid of it and only rely on the boards in Swift Package.

As a result, at various times the app was calling scenes from the storyboard in my app (which also had the assets) and at others it was calling scenes from the storyboard in the package (which didn't have access to the assets).

If I programmatically set the image or used nil to reference the bundle when I instantiated, it worked but in this instance it was done "properly" which failed because I hadn't migrated the image assets yet.

Put those in the package and now it works!!